# SQL Server : keep track of a running calculation monthly

Tags: sql-server

I have the following in Excel which I need to calculate in SQL Server:

[image]

The columns that needs to be calculated is `change` and `new_threshold`:

The formula for `change` is:

[image]

While the formula for new_threshold is:

[image]

I have tried to use the lead and lag methods SQL Server offers, but I can't seem to keep track of the calculation.

Here is one thing I've tried:

```
SELECT
    year_month,
    round(original_threshold, 0) original_threshold,
    round(case when original_threshold > isnull(lead(original_threshold) over (order by [year_month] desc), original_threshold)
        then isnull(lead(original_threshold) over (order by [year_month] desc), original_threshold)  - original_threshold
        else 0 end, 0) change,
    manualChange,
    round(original_threshold + case when original_threshold > isnull(lead(original_threshold) over (order by [program], [year_month] desc), original_threshold)
        then isnull(lead(original_threshold) over (order by [year_month] desc), original_threshold)  - original_threshold
        else 0 end + manualChange, 0) new_threshold
FROM 
    [Test].[dbo].[test]
```

which yields:

[image]

Edit:

Here is the insert statement if you want to test it

```
insert into [Test].[dbo].[test]
(
     [year_month]
    ,[original_threshold]
    ,[manualChange]
)

values
('2017_09', 401,    0),
('2017_08', 396,    0),
('2017_07', 397,   -5),
('2017_06', 389,   -7),
('2017_05', 393,    0),
('2017_04', 390,    0),
('2017_03', 412,    0),
('2017_02', 439,    0),
('2017_01', 458,    0)
```

Based on the values from this insert, I want to be able to calculate the `change` and `new_threshold` like in the Excel above.

Comment: And your version of sql server is ... sql server 2012 ? (and it is quicker if you are adding the insert statement for this table)

Comment: @sabinbio Yes. MSSQL 2012. I can also add the insert statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my idea:
-I used recursive approach,  - for this , added a `Row_number`, used this to join previous records

```
;WITH cte_Source AS
(SELECT 
    year_month
    ,original_threshold  
    ,manualChange
    ,CONVERT(int,LEFT(year_month,4)) As mYear
    ,CONVERT(int,RIGHT(year_month,2)) As mMonth
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(int,LEFT(year_month,4)),CONVERT(int,RIGHT(year_month,2))) AS RN
FROM
    #Test AS T
)
,cteR AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1)
        T.year_month
        ,T.original_threshold  
        ,T.manualChange
        ,0 AS change
        ,T.original_threshold  +  0 + T.manualChange AS  new_threshold
        ,T.RN
    FROM cte_Source AS T
    --WHERE T.year_month ='2017_01'
    ORDER BY T.mYear * 100 + T.mMonth ASC


    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        S.year_month
        ,S.original_threshold  
        ,S.manualChange
        ,CASE WHEN  S.original_threshold > R.new_threshold THEN R.new_threshold - S.original_threshold ELSE 0 END AS  change
        ,S.original_threshold  
            + CASE WHEN  S.original_threshold > R.new_threshold THEN R.new_threshold - S.original_threshold ELSE 0 END 
            + S.manualChange AS  new_threshold
        ,S.rn AS rn
        FROM cte_Source AS S
            INNER JOIN cteR AS R
            ON r.RN + 1 = S.RN 

)

select  
    [year_month]
    ,[original_threshold]
    ,[change]
    ,[manualChange]
    ,[new_threshold]    
from cteR
```

output for it:

```
year_month original_threshold change      manualChange new_threshold
2017_01    458                0           0            458
2017_02    439                0           0            439
2017_03    412                0           0            412
2017_04    390                0           0            390
2017_05    393                -3          0            390
2017_06    389                0           -7           382
2017_07    397                -15         -5           377
2017_08    396                -19         0            377
2017_09    401                -24         0            377
```

Comment: Interesting idea! :) Only thing though. Your're selecting `[new_threshold]` in both of your CTE's. This is supposed to be calculated. I see my insert statement was a little bit confusing. I'll update it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Updated now. Again, sorry about that.

Comment: You're welcome! is my pleasure

Comment: Just curious: would it be possible to achieve this using aggregation with window-functions (over-clause), or it recursion the best (or only) option here?

Comment: We can try... it was my first try, but I stumble on something and I change "tactic" to use recursive. Because you are calculating the field `change` base on the previous  threshold, which is also calculated...

Comment: don't get me wrong. I thought recursion was a great solution :) It was mostly out of curiosity. The only thing I didn't quit understand with this solution was where you create the row-number. Why split up year and month like that? Cant we just use `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY  year_month)`?

Comment: year_month is of type varchar , so to be sure that every record is in the right place. with type varchar  I'm not sure . you can test it with `ORDER BY year_month`